# Should backend send data 2D array or array object to view

Tags: php, arrays, json, model-view-controller

```
$data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//2D array (when mysql fetchAll, it came out like this)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20,
            [title] => "testing1",
            [time] => 1471936066
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18,
            [title] => "testing2",
            [time] => 1467780284
        )
);

//array object
Array(
        {
            "id" : 20,
            "title" : "testing1",
            "time" : 1471936066
        },


        {
            "id" : 18
            "title" : "testing2",
            "time" : 1467780284
        }
);
```

I have a question about sending data format to view at backend (sometimes it will need to be JSON string for JS, but not all the time)

should I send 2D array to view or should I convert data to array object and send it to view file?

Comment: It depends how you're sending and receiving the data. Ideally, you should send it as a JSON object.

Comment: if i need to send to JS, i will do JSON, but my question is if its a view php file when page load?

Comment: How you send it is 100% up to you, what kind of data you're passing and on your applications needs. The only thing I would say is to be consistent. Chose one way and stick to it.

Comment: If I send to view php file in JSON, I need to json_encode than decode again, sounds unnecessary and make it more complex

Comment: While you can use json_decode to decode it again, you cannot use 2D php array when you're consuming it from JS.

Comment: +1 to Magnus,
Choose one way. It'll be much easier to maintain.